# How to post a comment on photo or video?

Tags: graph, facebook-graph-api

How to post a comment on image or video, using the graph api?

And how to post an image, using the graph api?

I am trying to code like this, using this URL but it's not working properly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?acess_token=tokengenerated&method=post&picture=Image/photo1.bmp
```

Does it require to add `@` character ?

If I add it, it still doesn't work properly:

```
&picture=@Image/photo1.bmp
```

It gives me an error stating that the picture URL is not properly formatted.

Answer (score -1):

https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=tokengenerated&method=post&picture=Image/photo1.bmp

Might it be a spelling mistake:

```
acess => access
```